# Object key value destructuring in array arguments

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to follow a d3 [tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/calendar-view) to implement a Github-style Calendar View. What I am a bit confused about is some of the syntax used. On the line where {close: previous} is specified as the first argument of the callback, I don't understand the object destructuring that is happening. Could someone please explain what `close` and `previous` refer to in the innermost context?

```
data = {
  const data = await d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/354a9c93174a17eb6b80f4678e3d3ae9/raw/9d20ec96a40cc3fd5b8ddc9a306bd7397d5cfd16/dji.csv", d3.autoType);
  return d3.pairs(data, ({close: previous}, {date, close}) => {
    return {date, value: (close - previous) / previous};
  });
}
```

By the way, `data` is an array of objects with the following properties:

`date`, `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, `volume`

Comment: I think the "first" `close` is being renamed to `previous`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the innermost context `close` refers to `close` in the second destructuring and `previous` refers to `close` in the first one.

As per the ECMAScript 2015 specifications you can specify an identifier reference in an object destructuring assignment, so you can declare a variable named the identifier after the colon and the value will be put into that reference. **Sometimes it is referred to as renaming.**

You can even even use initializers like `({a: b = def}) => {}` which will act as default value.

See specs: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation

Answer (score 0):

it is just a way of renaming a property. in your scenario close is being renamed as previous.